# Is it technically correct to say that $0 = 2\pi$ in trigonometry?

Tags: trigonometry

We know that the sine, cosine or any other trigonometric ratio of 0 and that of $2\pi$, $4\pi$...
 and so on, are the same.

So, is it technically correct to say that $$0=2\pi = 4\pi... $$ in trigonometry?

I can't think of an argument otherwise since they are indistinguishable in the trigonometric functions and operations (as far as I have learned).

A point is we can say that $0 \ne \pi $ since even though $sin(0) = sin (\pi)$, but cos(0) $\ne cos(\pi)$. 
But obviously, *that* is not the case with 0 & 2$\pi$.

Comment: No, they are different numbers. $0$ is simply not equal to $2\pi$.

Comment: Isn't $\cos\frac x2$ a trigonometric function?

Comment: You might as well ask: "is it techically correct to say that saturday next week is the same day as saturday today?". It is better to say that the elements are "equivalent" in a specific context. Then $0\neq2\pi$ but $[0]=[2\pi]$.

Comment: @bof, oh I didn't think of that! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not correct.

Here $2\pi$ is one full rotation, whereas, say, $6\pi$ is three full rotations.

Comment: So it doesn't matter that they have the same result when used in *any* trigonometric operation?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't matter, @MrReality.

Answer (score 1):

They are not equal as numbers, so not really. You can say, though, that

$$
\sin(t) = \sin(t + 2k\pi) \\
\cos(t) = \cos(t + 2k\pi)
$$

for each $k\in \mathbb{Z}$ . I think this conveys what you're trying to represent.

Answer (score 0):

That might work for some mathematics. However, in Physics you would have many problems. If you are trying to calculate angular velocity and say you rotated $2 \pi$ in one second, according to your statement, you rotated $0$ in one second, so your angular velocity is zero.

However, it is true that in maths most times, although it is not entirely correct, they may be considered as the same, as it doesn't affect almost any calculations in trig functions. That is why in trig equations you always consider the smallest solution. However, be careful if you have a trig function and something else.

For example, $f(x)= \frac{\sin (x)}{x}$ is not defined for $x=0$ but is defined for $x= 2 \pi$.

Same goes for something lik $\sin (x) -x$.

Comment: "it doesn't affect almost any calculations in trig functions"- see bof's comment.

Answer (score 0):

They're equal in the group $\;\mathbf R/2\pi\mathbf Z$, not in $\;\mathbf R$, just as $S^1$ is not $[0,1)$ or $\;\mathbf Z/5\mathbf Z\ne\{\,0,1,2,3,4\,\}$.